# Haskell - Shuffling a list with different types?

Tags: haskell

I am very new to Haskell, I started learning Haskell some days ago for a course that I have. In this course there is an assignment, or homework, that I am stuck with at the moment. I would appreciate hints and explanations to my problem more than full, outright answers, since this is homework, and as such I do not want to take credit for another's work.

The assignment is to write a shuffling function (`skyffla`). The actual shuffling is not what I need help understanding, but rather one of the tests that the algorithm should pass. I'll mark the algorithm to the shuffling section with parentheses as to denote it as less important.

(`skyffla` shuffles by taking the first element, the third element, the fifth element and so on, until all the odd indices were taken, and then append these to a list.

The remaining elements in the first list should thereafter be processed by the same method, and appended onto the list that was first processed. And on, and on, until there is only one element left, which is then lastly appended onto the list.

If I for example input:

```
skyffla [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

it will give me:

```
1: _[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11] ++ skyffla ([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12])_
2: _[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11] ++ [2, 6, 10] ++ skyffla ([4, 8, 12])_
3: _[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 2, 6, 10] ++ [4, 12] ++ skyffla([8])_ 
(4): _[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 2, 6, 10, 4, 12, 8]_
```

This is exactly what my code does, and the actual shuffling is working just as it is intended. But as I mentioned, there is one test that I can't pass with my current implementation.)

So, one of the tests is that skyffla should take: `[3.4, 2.3, 5, 185, 23]` and return: `_[3.4, 5, 23, 2.3, 185]_`.

With the code that I  have, I get:  `_[3.4, 5.0, 23.0, 2.3, 185.0]_`

This is correct except for the ".0" that is appended unto *5*, *185,* and *23*.

Why is this?

How can I make it so that "5.0" for instance instead would be listed as "5"?

My code looks as follows:

```
skyffla :: [a] -> [a]
skyffla [] = []
skyffla xs
    | length xs == 1 = xs
    | otherwise = dropUnevenElements xs ++ skyffla newList  where
    newList = takeUnevenElements xs

dropUnevenElements :: [a] -> [a]
dropUnevenElements [] = []
dropUnevenElements (x:y:xs) = x:dropUnevenElements xs
dropUnevenElements x = x


takeUnevenElements :: [a] -> [a]
takeUnevenElements [] = []
takeUnevenElements (x:y:xs) = y:takeUnevenElements xs 
takeUnevenElements x = []
```

Comment: `dropUnevenElements x = x`?

Comment: And lists can only contain one type of elements.

Comment: Is 'skyffla' some weird phonetic translation of 'shuffle'? It should really be something like 'blanda'.

Comment: You can't have list whose elements are of different types. How is the test expressed?

Comment: Use `_` for values you don't care about (eg. `x:_:xs`).

Comment: The question title doesn't really reflect the content. Also, unless the output is validated *as a string* (which sounds like a terrible idea), the `.0` won't matter at all. It's possible that whoever wrote the sample output simply didn't think about how `show` works for most floating-point types in Haskell.

Comment: Since this is about a homework problem, I'm pretty sure this is off-topic. Only your instructor can actually tell you if you've interpreted the instructions much too strictly (a frighteningly common thing for students to do...) or if this entirely trivial difference in expected output actually matters. Chances are, whoever wrote the problem simply computed the expected output in their head, as opposed to running the program (if they even wrote it as a part of writing the question...) and copy-pasting the actual output produced by Haskell.

Comment: @user2407038 The current SO policy is that being homework is not a sufficient reason to close-vote the question as off topic. A few years ago we had the "homework" close-vote reason, but now it's gone because of the new policy. Now, most "do the work for me" questions are closed as too broad, while questions showing effort and asking for specific issues are kept open. (Personally, I now tend to upvote good honest questions which clearly state that it is homework, inviting help on small issues rather than a full solution)

Comment: @chi Sorry, I expressed this wrong. It's not off-topic just because it's homework; it's off-topic because it's a question about a specific requirement of a problem, but the author of the problem is not the author of the question, so no clarification can reasonably be expected from the author of the question (and also that information would be the answer itself). There are already two answers which make opposite assumptions about the question (one is "the requirement is silly, here's why"; the other is "here's how you satisfy the requirement").

Comment: @user2407038 Ah, I see now what you mean. The question is indeed about how to interpret the lack of ".0" in the requirement, which ultimately only the author of the question can answer. Still, I think one can make a really good guess for it, by saying that the provided reference output provides the value, and not the string representation of it. I find this to be very likely, also because achieving that exact output string would require some handling which is pointless as an homework exercise. Even if it's not 100% certain, I think a good guess here can still be useful to the OP.

Comment: @chi "I think a good guess here can still be useful to the OP." - indeed, which is why I have no intention to close/down vote. However, to be potentially more useful to all future readers, I am hoping that OP can rephrase the question slightly. But I don't see an obvious, objectively superior way to do so, so instead I just explain my reasoning for wanting this (aside: this has gotten very meta... I guess that's why we have the meta stack exchanges).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that your code is correct.

By the time the list reaches your function, all the elements are already the same type

```
ghci> [3.4, 2.3, 5, 185, 23]
[3.4,2.3,5.0,185.0,23.0]
```

because all lists in Haskell are homogeneous from the get-go.  (Here `5` is interpreted as `fromInteger 5`, which casts it to whatever type is needed in its context)

If you are comparing the output as a string, then you will have this problem. If you are testing them as lists of numbers, it's not a problem.

```
ghci> skyffla [3.4, 2.3, 5, 185, 23] == [3.4, 5, 23, 2.3, 185]
True
```

So what you are really facing is a display problem.  Chris Martin suggests `Data.Decimal`, which is one approach.  My perspective is that you don't have a problem, your code is correct, and it's your handling of test cases that needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be using a [Decimal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Decimal-0.4.2/docs/Data-Decimal.html) type.

```
λ> import Data.Decimal

λ> [3.4, 5, 23, 2.3, 185] :: [Decimal]
[3.4,5,23,2.3,185]
```

Comment: Add another dependency just to get rid of a trailing `.0`?

Comment: As opposed to using floating-point numbers where they aren't appropriate for the sake of avoiding adding a dependency? Heck yeah

Comment: You could could format the numbers in other ways. And since this is a homework question with (presumably) rigid constraints, it might not even be allowed.

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk, but as it currently stands, your answer doesn't address the question in full.

Comment: Since the OP states it's homework, I doubt this was the intended solution.